# R: Hover Event in Shiny App

Tags: r, hover, shiny

I have a datatable within a Shiny app containing thousands of records and 10 fields. One of the fields, 'Notes', contains the body of a unique email sent to each record. Due to the size of some of the emails, it takes up a lot of room in the datatable. I would like to create an info icon for each row that when hovered over will display the email associated with that row in a popup window which will subsequently go away after moving the mouse off of the icon. Is this possible in Shiny?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. First, you'll need to process that email text as HTML and add the following tags:

```
<i class='fa fa-info-circle' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='YOUR EMAIL TEXT'></i>
```

Depending on the size of your email, that tooltip might become a bit heavy, but this does what you want it to do.

Note that this is assuming you're running shinyDashboard (although I think any of the options - fluidPage, navbarPage etc - will work).

You also need to set escape = FALSE in `datatable(x, escape = FALSE)`

You can have a look at this implementation. For a table demo, click on **GO**, then click on the 'Health Behaviors' tab.

http://healthpolicy.ucla.edu/health-profiles/adults/Pages/dashboard.aspx

Comment: Thanks. This is a great example of a Shiny application. Perfect.

Comment: Sure thing! One comment: you can probably also append an <i> to each row within a column using Javascript, so doing it at the dataframe construction level is not the only way.